# Custom Views Placed Into a Gallery Layout Appear Too Large

Tags: android

I want to display a series of my own descendent class of View in a Gallery layout but when it is displayed, each of my custom views in the gallery is too large i.e. they exceed the border.

I've set (in XML) the background for each view as `"android:galleryItemBackground"` and handle onMeasure() etc in my descendent View class but for some reason my view is always drawn larger than the background.

Could anyone give me any idea what else I need to implement in my custom view class?

Thanks

The onDraw() method is here:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){


        /* Draw dial scale-arc */
        canvas.drawArc(scaleArcRect, scaleArcStart, scaleArcSweep, false, scaleArcPaint);
        canvas.drawArc(innerScaleArcRect, scaleArcStart, scaleArcSweep, false, innerScaleArcPaint);
        /* Draw the scale-arc ticks */
        drawScaleTicks(canvas);

        /* Add text to dial */
        //canvas.drawText(scaleFactorText, sFactorTextRect.left, sFactorTextRect.bottom, scaleTextPaint);

        drawScaleLegend(canvas);

        /*Draw the pointer */
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(drawAngle,this.viewWidth/2,this.viewHeight/2);
        canvas.drawPath(pointerPath, pointerPaint);
        canvas.restore();


        //canvas.drawText(scaleFactorText, sFactorTextRect.left,this.viewHeight/2, scaleTextPaint);

        /* Update position feedback variables */
        actualAngle = drawAngle;

        /* signal to compute thread that the position has been updated */
        isCommanded  = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving your custom views a `LayoutParams` when you receive them from the `Adapter.getView()`method.

Comment: Tried. I set a size there and it does resize my custom view but still it is larger than the background

Comment: Then the math on the LayoutParams is wrong, the background size to the gallery is different than you expect or when you draw the custom view, it's drawing larger than you think.

Comment: Yes I would tend to agree with you there but I don't understand how it's happening. My custom view draws to what it is told by the containing group. I'm just puzzled as to why this is occuring

Comment: Do you do any canvas drawing?

Comment: Yes I do. In the onDraw() method I draw out what it is I want to display (which are some arcs, lines, text etc). I'm pretty sure I obey size restrictions there as I use size parameters which are set from the onSizechanged() method.

Comment: Can you post the whole onDraw(Canvas) method please?

Comment: posted. (though some private methods excluded)

Comment: Ok, from looking at it, the onDraw does look to be the problem. Refer to <a href="http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/">this tutorial</a> for a better source explantion than I can give. Heck, I think it may even be related to what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's just what I want and what I've been trying to achieve!

Comment: Ahhh I realise now that because I am using a Gallery, there is a default 'overlap' of each view. by setting the spacing to '0' I can get views to neatly butt up against each other but that link you gave was useful for the overall effect I'm trying to achieve. Basically it's similar to my own but gives a better effect.

Comment: I am very happy I stumbled on that tutorial. It teaches so much about how custom views work.